# I failed a review audit for a "spam" false positive

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam, late-answers

Reviewing a late post that referred to one of several links mentioned in the original question. I was given the following message:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review
> carefully

As such, I confirmed that the link provided was not spam but was one of the links provided by the OP, and clicked "No action needed". Then I got a message that this was review audit and I failed.

I'm pretty sure this was just a false positive by the system, but I wanted to see if I accidentally did something wrong. Here's the link to the audit results, including the question and answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6225300

Did I unknowingly make an incorrect diagnosis, or is this just a bug in the system?

Also, what are the consequences of this audit failure? Is there some way for me to formally dispute this?

Comment: I wouldn't classify that as spam, a poor answer, yes, but not spam.

Comment: Looks like it was deleted by the community through the low-quality review queue (probably on claim that it's link only - it's not actually flagged as spam). I think it probably should not have been deleted - it's not a *great* answer, but it is attempting to explain something specifically brought up in the question.

Comment: Okay, that was my take on it too.  It's not a particularly thorough answer but is it correct and specifically addresses part of the OPs question, so it would have been inappropriate to flag it or downvote it.

Comment: Why reviewers are expected to identify spam remains a mystery. This is the primary reason I gave up reviewing many years ago. If the system can already identify spam, or possible spam, what do reviewers have to do with it? and why should they be expected to click on possibly harmful links? And then when you fail you are asked to acknowledge your error, even when you don't accept that you've made one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The system uses that warning for *possible* spam, which isn't an indication that it is spam or that it should be handled in a different way. Enough thresholds were tripped (based on various information the system has) that this post might have some likelihood of being spam, so a warning was presented.

That shouldn't change the way you review the post, just cause you to take a closer look at it. Voting shouldn't change when that warning is presented. You should review that answer as you would any other in the Late Answers review queue, just maybe look at it a little harder than you would otherwise.

It was flagged as "very low quality", downvoted, and eventually removed [in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6085752). This caused it to be used as a potential audit case. You failed that audit because you chose "No Action Needed" on what the system considered a non-answer, not because it was treated as spam.

Comment: Was it really deleted by the poster? The note on it says "deleted Oct 27 at 7:04" , not "deleted by owner..." (as another deleted answer on the same question says).

Comment: @AndrewMedico - You're right, missed that. It was deleted due to votes in review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6085752

Comment: Okay, that's good to know.  Although I still disagree subjectively that this answer really meets the threshold for "very low quality", as it is correct and specifically addresses part of the OP's question.  Am I misunderstanding what should be considered a "very low quality" answer, or did I just get unlucky in this case?

Comment: @CaseyRule - Hard for me to tell. It's not a great audit, I'll give you that, but the answerer leaving a comment like "Again, the link I provided does not provide an answer" would seem to indicate it's not an answer. There seemed to be near-unanimous agreement to remove it in review, so I defer to that.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll be more vigilant in the future for answers that aren't really providing answers.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The answerer wasn't even providing that link; it exists in the original question and the answerer is explaining what something that confused the OP in that link itself means.

Comment: @BradLarson It sounds like the answerer was responding to reviewers' (now-removed) canned link-only comments (“While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”), trying to explain that it was not a link-only answer.

Comment: That "possible spam" notice also confused me. It seemed the system was asking me to confirm if the question/answer is indeed a spam. So I failed the review audit. Not sure how that copy could be improved, though.